# Twitter OAuth integration on Debian apparently broken by wheezy/PHP 5.4.4 upgrade

Tags: php, twitter, debian, upgrade, twitter-oauth

Today I upgraded a Debian box from `squeeze` to `wheezy` (since nobody is bothering to fix the `bash` environment vulnerability on `wheezy`).  This included an upgrade of PHP to version 5.4.4, specifically 5.4.4-14+deb7u14.

Now a previously working Twitter OAuth integration (using [TwitterOAuth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) -- was a recent version, is now current) is reporting error 215, "Bad Authentication data", from all requests.  My authentication data, of course, has not changed (which I've verified).

Any ideas on what might be causing this and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today the Twitter integration quietly started working again.  So apparently *that's* a thing now.

Leaving this question up in case somebody runs into the same situation so they can be reassured that there's some likelihood their software will just randomly become functional again.